# Azure DevOps VsTest task version 2.167.1 failing

Tags: azure-devops, vstest, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Azure DevOps VSTest task is failing on private agent with an error `##[error]Error: The process 'C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.167.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1`

How can I specify a previous version of VsTest task to get a successful build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I specify a previous version of VsTest task to get a successful build?

I am afraid there is no such way to use the previous version of VsTest task. You could use the `v1.*` version of the VSTest task.

**In addition**, the **reason** for this issue should be that the VSTest task supported .Net Framework `4.6.2` from version `2.163.1`.

So, to resolve this issue, please check the .NET framework version installed on the build agent machine. If the .NET framework version installed on the machine is `4.6.1` or less than that then can you please try upgrading the .Net framework version to `4.6.2`.

Please check [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12170) for some more details.

Hope this helps.